# Reverse the direction of \pause in a matrix

Tags: beamer

What I'm trying to do is to display the third row first then the second row and then the first row, is there a way to do that? Thanks again in advance for your help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
$\begin{bmatrix}
  \pause
  1  & -3 & 0            & 5            \\
  \pause
  -1 & 1  & 5            & 2            \\
  \pause
  0  & 0  & \tfrac{7}{2} & \tfrac{7}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\onslide`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
$\begin{bmatrix}
  \onslide<3->
  1  & -3 & 0            & 5            \\
  \onslide<2->
  -1 & 1  & 5            & 2            \\
  \onslide<1->
  0  & 0  & \tfrac{7}{2} & \tfrac{7}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the positions of the rows as follows:

```
$\begin{bmatrix}
0  &  0  &  \tfrac{7}{2}  & \tfrac{7}{2}  \\  
-1 &  1  & 5  & 2\\ 
1 & -3  & 0  & 5  \\
\end{bmatrix} $
```

The third row is at the first, then second row is at second and the first row is at the last.

It's output is as
[image: matrix output]